# MySQL disable table check constraints

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to disable custom table checks in MySQL?

Table checks were previously silently ignored by MySQL, since version 8.0.16 they are [implemented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) and enforced, but it seems that there is no way to turn them globaly.

MySQL has only **FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS** and **UNIQUE_CHECKS** variables, which are specific, there is nothing for check constraints.

My principal issue is that I need to add a check on big table. If this happens with a foreign key check, one can use the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK variable together with ALTER_TABLE and INPLACE algorihtm:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_constraint FOREIGN KEY (...) REFERENCES other_table, ALGORITHM=INPLACE
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Now because it seems that there is nothing to turn off checks globaly, there is no way to use the INPLACE algorithm with check constraint, the following will fail:

```
ALTER TABLE my_big_table
ADD CONSTRAINT only_some_numbers
CHECK (column_one >= 100 AND column_one <= 300), ALGORITHM=INPLACE;
```

It seems that MariaDB has a variable to allow this:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#check_constraint_checks

I did not find anything in MySQL documentation. Is there a different way to achieve such inplace addition of new check constraint?